# new import with imports pre-def

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, definition

how to import foo module like this example.

**main.py :**

```
import time
from foo import main
return main()
```

**foo.py :**

```
def main()
    print 'hello', time.time()
```

I tried to explain, there are two or more files, I wanted to upload a import already defined by another file without defining in what will be loaded, like my example

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not how Python works. Names *must* be available in the scope in which they are used. There is a scope that is always accessible, but modifying it is generally frowned upon since it makes code harder to read and use.